# How to restore session / application indicator in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, indicator

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm using classic GNOME.

While trying to restore sound, I somehow removed the whole indicator area on the right side on the system menu.

There is no cog, user switcher, calendar, email, sound, WiFi... - nothing at all.

On the other side (left) I still have the menu - Applications & Places.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt+right-click on the panel and select 'add to panel'. From there choose "indicator applet". Refer to the following figures:

[image]

[image]

Although on 12.04 I think this applet is called "indicator-applet-complete" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! :) Panel restored. Seems after more than a year using Ubuntu, I still know nearly nothing about it :)